# Local database in Visual Studio wpf, data adding doesnt work

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, addition, mdf, local-database

I am trying to add some data to my empty table `OBJEDNAVKY(columns:CisloStolu,Cena,Zaplacena,Nazev)` in local database `MDF` (using `Ado.Net Data Entity Model`), in Visual Studio 2013. But it doesn't work.

Can you find the problem? Here is the code.

```
public void VlozObjednavkuDb(int Cena, int CisloStolu, int zaplacena, string nazev)
{
    using (JidelnicekEntities4 databaze = new JidelnicekEntities4())
    {
        try{
            Objednavky objednavka = new Objednavky
                {
                    CisloStolu = CisloStolu,
                    Cena = Cena,
                    Zaplacena = zaplacena,
                    Nazev = nazev
                };
            databaze.Objednavkies.Add(objednavka);
            databaze.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception) { MessageBox.Show("Ojednavka nebyla provedena"); }
    }
}
```

I was trying to add some data from listbox first, so I tried to add some basic data, but it doesn't work even with this.

```
VlozObjednavkuDb(1, 1, 0, "p");
```

The table stays empty.

Thank you for every advice.

Comment: Show the connection string

Comment: SaveChanges returns the number of rows affected in the database do ` x= databaze.SaveChanges();` and check the value of X, if x > 0 then you're updating the wrong file

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\VisualStudio\Restaurace\Restaurace\Jidelnicek.mdf;Integrated Security=True

Comment: JAT , I've tried your suggestion and x = 0 .

Comment: Try  databaze.Entry(objednavka).State = EntityState.Added; before calling SaveChanges

Comment: Thank you , but anyway, im going to work with sdf, I found out its more useful for my small program.

Comment: Still the same problem, its not adding anything to database, but I can read from it. Even with your last help..any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it catching an error?

Comment: Yes! on  databaze.SaveChanges();

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: DbUpdateException ... An error occurred while updating the entries.

Comment: What else? Inner exception?

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/5uxxrspmr/inner_Ex.png

Comment: Yeah, read the error, "A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index ... PK_Objednavky"  You're trying to insert an Objednavky with a key that already exists.

Comment: Whats your primary key? Cena?

Comment: I see, but my primary key is Id

Comment: Can you check if the Id column's identity is set to auto increment?

Comment: Yes, I already fixed that, it doesnt show any error now, but still not updating the Database.

Comment: Make the  x= databaze.SaveChanges() test again, what is x?

Comment: well, I just found out something really disturbing... when I insert 5 objects = id 1-5...database is empty, but then if i try to insert it again, it throws an error... but in this situation, if i give id 6-10, there is no error again... does it mean im looking into wrong Database? but where is my database then?

Comment: Yeah, look in your bin/debug folder